# AJAX cannot print elements onclick

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have got 2 files, one named index.php and one named api.php. I am trying to retrieve some data from my DB and I've done this simple example before trying to put the code into my project. In the api.php file I ve got the following:

```
$connessione=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
$scelta_db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die(mysql_error());
$idM=67;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM map_comment WHERE idMap ='$idM'");
$array = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result) )
{
 $array[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

While in the index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Output: </h3>
<div id="output">Attacco qua sotto</div>
<button onclick ='show_comments'>Carica commenti </button>
 <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function show_comments()
{

$.ajax({
  url: 'api.php',                  
  data: "",                        
  dataType: 'json',                
  success: function(rows)          
  {
    for (var i in rows)
    {
        var row = rows[i];

        var idU = row[1];
        var text_map = row[3];

   $('#output').append("<b> idU: </b>"+idU+"<b>text </b>"+text_map)
   .append("<hr />");

    }
  }
});

};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that it does not seems to "append" nothing and I dunno what I am doing wrong. I KNOW I should use mysqli, I'll fix that. Plus: HOW can I "send" a $idM to the api.php from the index.php (for example an $id already defined in the index.php)?

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not called when you click the button, in an onclick attribute you're not setting a function but rather writing code to execute. See example below

```
<button onclick ='show_comments()'>...
```

To send the id, you can use the data parameter

```
data: {id: 67},
```

Since this is a GET request you can use the php super global $_GET to retrieve the value `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: Ok, I think I've understand that. So how could I call the function after clicking on a button? I'm a bit confused :-S Sorry!

Comment: Damn it! I forgot the brackets!!! So dumb and tired! Thx very much! :) I'll try to put that code into my main project hoping it will work  ;)